# Piecewise Continuity and Integrability...

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, piecewise-continuity

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x$, if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = -x$, if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

**Proof Idea**: There is a theorem that says: if $f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval, then $f$ is Riemann integrable over that interval. So, my idea is to show that $f$ is not continuous so that it is not Riemann integrable.

To this end, we must find $\epsilon_0 > 0$ and $c \in [0, 1]$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ with $x \in [0, 1]$ satisfying $|x - c| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(c)| \geq \epsilon_0$. I want to use the density of the irrationals somewhere, but I am not sure where it fits. I know that

$$|f(x) - f(c)| = |x - c|, \: \text{or} \: |f(x) - f(c)| = |x + c|, \: \text{or} \: |f(x) - f(c)| = |-x + c|,$$

depending on if $x, c$ are rational or irrational.

Also, I know that there exists a rational $r \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ such that $|x - r| > \delta. Then,

$$|f(x) - f(x)| \leq |f(x) - f(r)| + |f(r) - f(c)| = |x - r| + |r - c| < |x - r| + \delta > \delta + \delta = 2\delta,$$

so take $\epsilon_0 = 2\delta$, yeah?

Edit: I just added the above "Also, I know...".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to compute Upper and Lower Riemann sum and take into account that you can always find a rational and an irrational on every nondegenerate closed interval.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot.

Comment: There is a characterization theorem, due to Henri Lebesgue, which states that $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$ iff $f$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous almost everywhere (in the sense that the set $\{x\mid f\mbox{ is discontinuous at } x\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the theorem goes only in one direction. In other words proving that $f$ isn't continous on closed bounded region doesn't imply that $f$ isn't Riemann integrable. Indeed, note that $f$ having a single jump discontinuity isn't continuous, yet it is Riemann integrable. Hence your proof isn't valid.

You can prove the claim by computing the lower Riemann sum and the upper Riemann sum. For the upper one we have that:

$$R_n = \frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sup_{x \in \left[\frac in, \frac{i+1}{n}\right]} f(x)  = \frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {i+1} n = \frac 1{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2n}$$

For the lower sum we have that:

$$r_n = \frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \inf_{x \in \left[\frac in, \frac{i+1}{n}\right]} f(x) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {-(i+1)} n = \frac 1{n^2} \frac{-n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{-(n+1)}{2n}$$

Now note that $\lim R_n = \frac 12$, while $\lim r_n = - \frac 12$. As both limits don't agree we conclude that $f$ isn't Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you have $-i/n$ as the infimum for the lower sum. Why is it not $i/n$?

Comment: @TaylorMcMillan First of all note that both of the numbers above should be $i+1$, not $i$. See my edit. For you question note that $f$ takes negative values at irrational points. Then we can find irrational numbers arbitrarily close to $-\frac{i+1}{n}$, so it has to be their infinum, as it is also a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a theorem that says that if $f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval, then $f$ is Riemann integrable. That theorem says *nothing* about what happens if $f$ is *not* continuous. So, your proof doesn't work.

You could approach the problem proving that every superior sum is greater than $\frac12$ and that every inferior sum is smaller than $-\frac12$.

Comment: Isn't there something that states if the set of discontinuities is finite, then the function is Riemann integrable? So if I show that the set of discontinuities is uncountable (say on the irrationals), then I have the answer, right? I will attempt your suggestion though.

Comment: @TaylorMcMillan Again, you are attempting to assert the *converse* of a theorem.  A result and its converse do not have the same truth values.

Comment: The characteristic function of the Cantor set is Riemann integrable, although it has uncountably many discontinuity points.